# Newly unseen api from portable class library in Visual Studio 2012 RTM

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi this is first time question in sof.

I suppose this is caused by differnt support between VS2012 RC and RTM.

I had a portable class library in VS2012 RC.
I committed to TFS and download to new Windows 8 machine with VS 2012 RTM.

In old environment it works well, but in new one I got an error :

"Windows.Foundation" library not found @ "using Windows.Foundation" line

Microsoft guy said VS2012 support for portable library is limited, so unsupported library might pass compilation even portable library actually not support the library.

I am just using only Point in Windows.Foundation in the library, so I can easily exclude the class.
However, if we cannot rely on VS2012 code checker, what is the best way to keep portable library regulation ?

Thank you.